# UILabel not showing very large text in iPhone application

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

[image]I am creating a UILabel for showing text of around 16,000 lines in iphone application.It was working fine earlier to ios 6 but now in ios 6.0 or later it is not getting shown properly.

Nothing is getting shown in the label.It was working properly earlier and dont know whats going wrong in it.I have added UILabel on Scrollview.Code for the Label is as given below:=

```
infoUILabel.text = stringForLargeDescrition;
CGSize constraintSize;
    constraintSize.width = 285.0f;
    constraintSize.height = MAXFLOAT;

stringSizeforDescription = [strignForLabel sizeWithFont: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: 5] constrainedToSize: constraintSize lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
        infoUILabel.layer.cornerRadius = 10;    
        infoUILabel.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        [infoUILabel setFrame:CGRectMake(20,135, 285, stringSizeforDescription.height)];
        CGRect frame = infoUILabel.frame;
        frame.size = [infoUILabel sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(285, stringSizeforDescription.height)];
        infoUILabel.frame = frame;
        [infoUILabel alignTop];//this function will align the text to top of label
         backScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 230 + infoUILabel.frame.size.height);
     backScrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Please suggest,thanks in advance.

Comment: UITextView ....., is there a reason you are using a label and not a textview

Comment: Agreed with @Bergasms

Comment: UITextView is better option that UILabel for displaying large number of data. It provides scrolling as well, which in case of label you will need to handle by yourself.

Comment: Have u used the numberOfLines property of UILabel set to 0.

Comment: [infoUILabel setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap]; infoUILabel.numberOfLines = 0; Just Place this...

Comment: @sagrian,Bergasms,Shashank:= I dont want scrollable text in the application,so i have used UILabel.I know that there is option to make textview non editable but im not sure if thats a feasible solution.  I want show text in screen without making text scrollable but making the screen scrollable. Another thing is that i have taken infolabel using interface builder and have set value for nu,berOfLines there.

Comment: Sorry,I forgot to mention that it is working fine for smaller texts.

Comment: Ok.. but you can add the text to a uitextview. add the textview to the view heirachy. then set the textviews frame to the size of its content, and set editable and scrollable to false. 5 lines and it's done, no need to worry about line breaks :P

Comment: I have to use dynamic height of uitextview and disable scrolling but in uitextview if i will disable scrolling,touch of the uiscrollview will also disable.Anyone who has done editing/scrolling disabled in uitextview and also having touch enabled for the uitextview?

Comment: I have calculated the lines of the text i am showing in uilabel and it is more than 16,000.Anyone who can help me out

Comment: You need to use UITextView with scrolling enabled and editable/selected disabled (instead of UIScrollView & Content view & UILabel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use of textview showing dynamic text solved my problem,Code is as given below:

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 135, 285, 200)];
    textView.text = @"Very large text";
    textView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    textView.delegate = self;
    textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0f];
    textView.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    textView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    textView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    textView.backgroundColor= [UIColor whiteColor];
    CGRect rect      = textView.frame;

 CGSize constraintSize;
constraintSize.width = 285.0f;
constraintSize.height = MAXFLOAT;
stringSizeforDescription = [strignForLabel sizeWithFont: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: 12] constrainedToSize: constraintSize lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    rect.size.height = stringSizeforDescription.height + 20;//20 is some extra margin value 
    textView.frame   = rect;

[scrollView addSubview:textView];
[textView sizeToFit];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed numberOfLines property to set.

Add :

```
infoUILabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

It should work. Also remove this two lines from your code :

```
frame.size = [infoUILabel sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(285, stringSizeforDescription.height)];
infoUILabel.frame = frame;
```

Comment: @user378084 can you add the screen shot of what you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Try this it worked for me:

```
CGFloat height = 44.0;

CGSize labelSize = CGSizeMake(200.0, 20.0);

NSString *strTemp;

NSString *sectionData = @"Lengthy text.......Lengthy text.......Lengthy text.......";

labelSize = [sectionData sizeWithFont: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0] constrainedToSize: CGSizeMake(labelSize.width, 1000) lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

height =  (labelSize.height+40);

CGRect rect = lbl.frame;

rect.size.height = height;

lbl.frame = rect;
```

Answer (score -1):

Add

```
infoLabel.numberOfLines=0;
```

make sure that the MAXFLOAT has a bigger value than the expected

Comment: MaxFloat is bigger than expected

Answer (score -1):

Can you please try to set the text to UILabel at the end ... after you have set all the properties for UILabel.

Comment: I have added the image in the question,white background is been given to the uiLabel and screen is shown with the image in background.Transparent scrollview is added in the background of the UILabel.